# Object arrays - data not storing correctly for a deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am making a program that is going to involve a deck of cards. I know there are many ways to create a deck of cards, but in this case I make each card an object. This object stores 6 values: colour, suit, face, value, rank and IDNumber.

Then via a method called DeckOfCardsInitialiser, 52 card objects are stored in an array. This method initializes the cards, i.e. it computes and sets the objects (i.e. the cards) variables.

When checking to see if the cards have been set properly, I discover that all 52 cards are assigned to the values intended for only the last card, in this case King of Spades. I have done some debugging and know that the DeckOfCardsInitialiser is working as designed. Its just the object of arrays that is not not working as planned.

This is my first time using an array of objects, so that leads me to ponder whether I am making some silly mistakes. The program runs from Test -> DeckOfCardsInitialiser -> Card. I will print in reverse order to make it easier to follow.

Card

```
public class Card{
private static String suit ="";
private static String face="";
private static String colour="";

private static int value;
private static int rank;
private static int idNum;

public Card(){

}

public static void setSuit(String x){
    suit = x;
}

public static void setFace(String x){
    face = x;
}

public static void setColour(String x){
    colour = x;
}

public static void setValue(int x){
    value = x;
}

public static void setRank(int x){
    rank =  x;
}

public static void setIdNum(int x){
    idNum = x;
}

public static String getSuit(){
    return suit;
}

public static String getFace(){
    return face;
}

public static String getColour(){
    return colour;
}

public static int getValue(){
    return value;
}

public static int getRank(){
    return rank;
}

public static int getIdNum(){
    return idNum;
}
```

}

DeckofCardsInitialiser

```
public class DeckOfCardsInitialiser{

private static Card [] deckOfCards = new Card[52]; // makes an array with 52 cards

// ================================================== Constructor
// Constructor runs through all 52 'cards' and sets values to each one
public DeckOfCardsInitialiser(){
    for (int counter = 0; counter < deckOfCards.length; counter++){
        deckOfCards[counter] = new Card();
        setSuits(counter);
        setValues(counter);
    }
}

// Sets suit type and colour to each card
public static void setSuits(int x){
    if( x >= -1 && x <= 11 ){
        deckOfCards[x].setSuit("Hearts");
        deckOfCards[x].setColour("Red");
    }
    if( x >= 12 && x <= 24 ){
        deckOfCards[x].setSuit("Spades");
        deckOfCards[x].setColour("Black");
    }
    if( x >= 25 && x <= 37 ){
        deckOfCards[x].setSuit("Diamonds");
        deckOfCards[x].setColour("Red");
    }
    if( x >= 38 && x <= 51 ){
        deckOfCards[x].setSuit("Spades");
        deckOfCards[x].setColour("Black");
    }
}

// Sets face, rank, value & IDnum for each card
public static void setValues(int x){
    if (x == 0 || x == 13 || x == 26 || x == 39){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Ace");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(13);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(1);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 1 || x == 14 || x == 27 || x == 40){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Two");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(1);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(2);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 2 || x == 15 || x == 28 || x == 41){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Three");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(2);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(3);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 3 || x == 16 || x == 29 || x == 42){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Four");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(3);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(4);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 4 || x == 17 || x == 30 || x == 43){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Five");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(4);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(5);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 5 || x == 18 || x == 31 || x == 44){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Six");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(5);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(6);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 6 || x == 19 || x == 32 || x == 45){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Seven");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(6);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(7);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 7 || x == 20 || x == 33 || x == 46){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Eight");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(7);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(8);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 8 || x == 21 || x == 34 || x == 47){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Nine");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(8);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(9);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 9 || x == 22 || x == 35 || x == 48){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Ten");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(9);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(10);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 10 || x == 23 || x == 36 || x == 49){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Jack");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(10);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(10);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 11 || x == 24 || x == 37 || x == 50){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("Queen");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(11);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(10);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }
    if (x == 12 || x == 25 || x == 38 || x == 51){
        deckOfCards[x].setFace("King");
        deckOfCards[x].setRank(12);
        deckOfCards[x].setValue(10);
        deckOfCards[x].setIdNum(x);
    }

public static String getSuit(int x){
    String suit = deckOfCards[x].getSuit();
    return suit;
}

public static String getFace(int x){
    String face = deckOfCards[x].getFace();
    return face;
}

public static String getColour(int x){
    String colour = deckOfCards[x].getColour();
    return colour;
}

public static int getValue(int x){
    int value = deckOfCards[x].getValue();
    return value;
}

public static int getRank(int x){
    int rank = deckOfCards[x].getRank();
    return rank;
}

public static int getIdNum(int x){
    int idNum = deckOfCards[x].getIdNum();
    return idNum;
}
}
```

}

Test

public class Test{

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    DeckOfCardsInitialiser deckOfCards = new DeckOfCardsInitialiser();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 52; counter++){
        System.out.printf("%s of %s\n",deckOfCards.getFace(counter), deckOfCards.getSuit(counter));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attributes of class Card are defined as static, meaning they exist only one time, for the class.

You'll have to remove the `static` from the attributes, and from the getter and setter methods.

Comment: I thank you very much Thomas - this has been causing me much grief for the past 24 hours!